# how to show the same tooltip when mouse hover and text box onfocus on the information icon

Tags: html

```
 <i title="" id="iKeyDeliverables" class="greenExl glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip">
```

How to enable the same tool tip when mouse hover on the information icon, also when focus on the text box.

Answer (score 0):

You should try adding `data-trigger="hover focus"`

Another, more customizable option would be to use `data-trigger="manual"`, and then show / hide the tool tip yourself:

`$('#element').tooltip('show')`

`$('#element').tooltip('hide')`

Using the onFocus and onBlur events, and of course the onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave events.

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Really its helpful. Sorry for late reply

Comment: Hi Chandru, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.